# Place String on drawline in netbeans

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, graph, edges

I am making a graph GUI application in which I have algorithms where I can run simulations to show shortest path. Now, the graph works fine with undirected unweighted edges. Now I would like to have a weighted edges. What I want is to be able to place the weight on the line. [image: GUI]

Whenever an edge is placed, I have a function that places an edge into a list. An edge has an id, source, destination, and weight. I have a function which returns the weight. I will like to use getWeight to return weight and then place it on the edges. 
This is the code for drawing line

```
private void pnlGraphMouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    if (_selectedNode >= 0) {
        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(evt)) {
            Image buff = createImage(pnlGraph.getWidth() - 1, pnlGraph.getHeight() - 1);
            Graphics buffG = buff.getGraphics();
            buffG.drawImage(bufferImage, 0, 0, this);
            Point source = locations.get(_selectedNode);
            //buffG.drawLine(source.x, source.y,
                    //evt.getX(), evt.getY());
            drawArrow(buffG, source.x, source.y, evt.getX(), evt.getY());
            pnlGraph.getGraphics().drawImage(buff, 1, 1, this);

        } else if (SwingUtilities.isMiddleMouseButton(evt)) {
            locations.get(_selectedNode).x = evt.getX();
            locations.get(_selectedNode).y = evt.getY();
            graph();
            changesMade = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Once an edge is placed, I create an edge object and place it in a list

```
private void pnlGraphMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    if (_selectedNode >= 0) {
        int destination = nodeSelected(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
        if (destination >= 0 && destination != _selectedNode) {
            addEdge(Edgeid, _selectedNode, destination, (int)(Math.random() * 100));
            _selectedNode = -1;
            changesMade = true;
            Edgeid++;
        }
    }
    graph();
}

private void addEdge(int edgeId, int sourceid, int destid, final int weight) {
    Edge newEdge = new Edge(edgeId, vertices.get(sourceid), vertices.get(destid), 0, weight);
    edges.add(newEdge);
    printlnConsole(newEdge.getId()+" "+newEdge.getSource().getName()+" "+newEdge.getDest().getName()+" "+newEdge.getWeight());
    vertices.get(sourceid).vList().add(vertices.get(destid));
    vertices.get(destid).vList().add(vertices.get(sourceid));
}
```